# Make Executor dump part of queue

Tags: java, executor

At the moment I'm using the Executor:

```
Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

But my problem is, that if I put it too many tasks, they are executed too slowly and my UI hangs while the executor works through. So I want it to behave, that the executor only executes on task at a time. But when a new task is being submitted, I want him to drop the queued task if there are more than 5.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Executors#newSingleThreadExecutor` is just a convenience for direct instantiation of `ThreadPoolExecutor`, which gives you more configuration options. You can configure a `ThreadPoolExecutor` to use a single thread and a fixed-length queue, and give it a handler which dictates that the contents of the queue should be discarded when you submit a new task, something like this:

```
new ThreadPoolExecutor(
   1, 1, // single thread
   30, TimeUnit.SECONDS, // timeout, see javadoc
   new LinkedBlockingQueue(1), // queue with capacity 1 
   new ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardOldestPolicy() // ditch the queued task when a new one comes in
);
```

The key piece here is the fixed-size queue (1, in this case), and the rejection handler argument:

> A handler for rejected tasks that discards the oldest unhandled request and then retries execute